# generating a single outfile after analyzing multiple files in python

Tags: python

i have multiple files each containing 8/9 columns.

for a single file : I have to read last column containing some value and count the number of occurrence of each value and then generate an outfile.

I have done it like:

```
inp = open(filename,'r').read().strip().split('\n')  
out = open(filename,'w')  
from collections import Counter  
C = Counter()  
for line in inp:  
    k = line.split()[-1] #as to read last column  
    C[k] += 1  
for value,count in C.items():  
    x = "%s   %d" % (value,count)  
    out.write(x)  
    out.write('\n')  
out.close()
```

now the problem is it works fine if I have to generate one output for one input. But I need to scan a directory using `glob.iglob`function for all files to be used as input. And then have to perform above said program on each file to gather result for each file and then of course have to write all of the analyzed results for each file into a single OUTPUT file.

NOTE: During generating single OUTPUT file if any value is found to be getting repeated then instead of writing same entry twice it is preferred to sum up the 'count' only. e.g. analysis of 1st file generate:

```
123 6  
111 5  
0   6  
45  5
```

and 2nd file generate:

```
121 9  
111 7  
0   1  
22  2
```

in this case OUTPUT file must be written such a way that it contain:

```
123 6  
111 12 #sum up count no. in case of similar value entry  
0   7  
45  5  
22  2
```

i have written prog. for single file analysis BUT i'm stuck in mass analysis section.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise a empty dictionary at the top  of the program,
lets say, `dic=dict()`

and for each `Counter` update the `dic` so that the values of similar keys  are summed and the new keys are also added to the `dic`

to update `dic` use this:

`dic=dict( (n, dic.get(n, 0)+C.get(n, 0)) for n in set(dic)|set(C) )`

where `C` is the current `Counter`, and after all files are finished write the `dic` to the output file.

```
import glob
from collections import Counter
dic=dict()
g_iter = glob.iglob(r'c:\\python32\fol\*')
for x in g_iter:

    lis=[]
    with open(x) as f:
        inp = f.readlines()
    for line in inp:
        num=line.split()[-1]
        lis.append(num)
    C=Counter(lis)
    dic=dict( (n, dic.get(n, 0)+C.get(n, 0)) for n in set(dic)|set(C) )
for x in dic:
    print(x,'\t',dic[x])
```

Comment: 'll you please explain your code for me. I can't make it up !

Comment: can you provide the content of sample input file?

Comment: I have given it under 'NOTE:' section. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: that's output , I am asking for input content of files?

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
import glob

out = open(filename,'w')
g_iter = glob.iglob('path_to_dir/*')  
C = Counter()
for filename in g_iter:
    f = open(filename,'r')
    inp = f.read().strip().split('\n')
    f.close()
    for line in inp:
        k = line.split()[-1] #as to read last column
        C[k] += 1
for value,count in C.items():
    x = "%s %d" % (value,count)
    out.write(x)
    out.write('\n')
    out.close()
```

Comment: You beat me to it, but I would consider `C.update([line[-1] for line in inp])` instead of that way of updating the counter...

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Please answer the rest of the question too. itz more problematic to me.

Comment: Where is the rest of the question? My code reads all files from the directory and performs the counting action on all of them one by one and then writes the final count results in output file ( this was your problem, right?). I can not find any other problem asked in your question.

Comment: @SaeveshKumarSingh I think you focus only in code! see the text under 'NOTE:' section that is the second section of question!

Comment: this will not repeat any entry in out put file. the counters for all entries will be stored in Counter C, the code will open each file one-by-one -> get the last column for each line and if that entry is already in their it will increase the counter by one. In the end the counter will contain the counter for each entry which will be Sum of counts of that entry in all the files. Then the counters will be written in the file.

Answer (score 1):

After de-uglification:

```
from collections import Counter
import glob

def main():
    # create Counter
    cnt = Counter()

    # collect data
    for fname in glob.iglob('path_to_dir/*.dat'):
        with open(fname) as inf:
            cnt.update(line.split()[-1] for line in inf)

    # dump results
    with open("summary.dat", "w") as outf:
        outf.writelines("{:5s} {:>5d}\n".format(val,num) for val,num in cnt.iteritems())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this.

```
import glob
out = open("write.txt",'a')  
from collections import Counter  
C = Counter()  
for file in glob.iglob('temp*.txt'):
    for line in open(file,'r').read().strip().split('\n'):  
        k = line.split()[-1] #as to read last column  
        C[k] += 1  
for value,count in C.items():  
        x = "%s   %d" % (value,count)  
        out.write(x)  
        out.write('\n')  
out.close()
```